# Maximising efficiency of a data structure ordered by a person name using Java Collections

Tags: java, collections, time-complexity

I need to have a data structure mapped by the name of the person, which implies that duplicate keys will have to be stored. I would like to have log(n) times (at most) for insertions, deletions and searches.

Ideally, I would have a Hashtable mapped by a unique identifier, that will be generated upon insertion. By doing so, I have insertions in constant time. With an auxiliary ordered Balanced Tree with each entry being a reference to an entry in the Hashtable, I would be able to search/delete by name in logarithmic time, and print all the entries in linear time, ordered by name.

Is there a way to do this in Java by reusing the available Collections? Or at least a solution with similar complexity...

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157716/what-data-structure-could-i-use-to-find-the-phone-number-of-a-person-given-the-p), it is suggested that a Map will solve this problem. But from my understanding, no Map can deal with repeated keys properly.

Comment: Sorry, what? Do I understand it correctly that you want to store and then retrieve persons using their name as an ID? How would be two different people with the same name dealed with? What data do you need to store and by what data do you need to search by?

Comment: I need only to search by name. By reading the answers, I understood that MultiMap is what I want: after retrieving all the persons with the same name, the user will then choose according to the other data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question right, you want a MultiMap. There are a few implementations in [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) and [Commons-Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html), or you could roll your own using e.g. a HashMap (or TreeMap if you suspect your `.hashCode()` implementation is too slow or too poor, but I'd benchmark first) and a List or Set implementation as the value types.

Note that if you want to *iterate* over the values based on Name order, you're best off using a Tree-based Multimap: If the name is already the key, your order will be what you want without needing to do anything else.

Comment: When I first read about MultiMaps I didn't understand their details and discarded them, but now I realise this is the approach I should follow. I have just one more requirement, that MultiMap fails to accomplish: iterate the structure ordered by name. Any ideia on how to accomplish that?

Comment: If you have a TreeMultiMap and your persons are either inherently ordered by name or you have a `Comparator<Person>` that compares by name first, your iteration order will already be by name. One downside is the reduced lookup speed (O(log n) instead of O(1) amortized).

Comment: Interesting! Do you think having a TreeMultiMap along with the MultiMap, ordered by the Person name, and with the value being a reference to the associated Collection of Persons in the MultiMap would be a good solution as well?

Comment: I don't know too much about your use case, so the best way to find out is to write it and measure. Should you find that your version is too slow for some reason, you can always swap out the MultiMap implementation for something else.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to include this new info? That way it will be easier for other users with similar problems to find the optimal solution. I will then gladly mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

As you said yourself, Map will help you. For repeated keys, you should store list of Objects as values instead of Objects themselves. You can very well levarage Generics for this purpose to either store Object or List of Objects in the Value.

Edit: This degenerates to O(n) complexity in worst case for search (All entries have same name), but this case should be very very rare, so should probably ignore it.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the question. I wanted to say that no Map can have repeated keys, but instead I wrote that Maps could help me. Just edited! 

Can  you give an example of what you mean with "storing list of Objects as values instead of Objects themselves"? How can that help with the repeated keys? From your edit seems you're suggesting to have something like an HashMap indexed by a unique identifier, but that would degenerate all operations but the insertions.

Comment: By reading the second answer I understood your suggestion now! So, both search/removal by name degenerates in the way you explained, but I can't print the structure ordered by the name.

Answer (score 2):

If you agree to generating a unique ID per entity, then you should use a composite key consisting of the name and the unique ID. Make the key comparable by name, then by ID to break ties.

Then you just use a plain `TreeMap` for storage and retrieval. Especially take note of the `NavigableMap` API, which will allow you to find the best match for a key disregarding the differences in the ID part.

Comment: Can I have log(N) time in the insertions, searches and removals by name with this solution?

Comment: This is not the solution I am looking for then, but I am interested on this approach. So if I use a composite key in a TreeMap or a NavigableMap the way you suggested, the way to search and remove will still be to iterate the values? 

And why is not the insertion log(N)?

Comment: It was a mistake in my comment. `TreeMap` is O(log n) for insertion and removal and the `NavigableMap` operations, such as `floorEntry`, are `O(log n)` as well.

Comment: So basically a NavigableMap is a tree that can handle duplicate keys, and return sets/maps with several keys, matching some given criteria. Am I right? And if I decide to use a TreeMap with a composite key, and implement the comparators as you suggested, the tree would be ordered first by the person's name, and then by the unique identifier?

Comment: Not quite, `NavigableMap` is just a slice of `TreeMap`'s API. It doesn't handle duplicate keys and that's why you'll add the unique ID. It allows you to find a key that has the requested person's name by calling `floorEntry` or `ceilingEntry` with a key that has the name inside, plus a zero ID.